# Regularity theorem of minimizers

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation, nonlinear-analysis

During my self study to the calculus of variations I come across this problem. Because of my search, I know what I wanted to do but I need some help to do them.

The function $f:[-1,1] \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is defined by

$$f(x,\xi) = \left( w(x) \xi - 2 x w(x) \sin \frac{\pi}{x} + \pi w(x) \cos(\frac{\pi}{x}) \right)^2,$$

where

$$w(x) =
\begin{cases}
e^{- \frac{1}{x^2}},& x\not = 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}.$$

In this problem we consider the regularity of solutions of the Euler-Lagrange equation corresponding to the one-dimensional minimization problem

$$\inf_{u \in X} I[u],\,\,\, I[u]= \int_{-1}^1 f(x, u'(x)) dx,\,\,\, X=\{ u \in \operatorname{Lib}[-1,1]: u(-1) = u(1)=0 \}.$$

I want to prove the so-called **regularity theorem**; Let $\overline{u} \in \operatorname{Lib}[a,b]$ satisfy the integral Euler equation for the functional $\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x,u(x),u'(x)) dx$, where for every $x \in [a,b]$ the function $\xi \to f(x,\overline{u}(x),\xi)$ is strictly convex. Then $\overline{u}$ lies in $C^1 [a,b]$.

As far as reached, to prove the theorem we can solve the following sub-problems, to explain why the regularity theorem does not apply to this minimization problem.

**The steps are:** \item Showing that $f$ is infinitely differentiable, $\xi \mapsto f(x,\xi)$ is convex and $f_{\xi \xi} (x,\xi) > 0$ holds for all $x$ except for $x=0$.
Showing that the function

$$\overline{u}(x) = \begin{cases} x^2 \sin \frac \pi x,& x \not = 0\\ 0, & x=0\end{cases}$$
yields the minimum of the minimization problem. Also confirm that this function is Lipschitz continuous on $[-1,1]$.
And we show that there is no other minimizer except for the function $\overline{u}$ above. and we need to show that $\overline{u}$ does not belong to $C^1 ([-1,1])$. The main step is to explain why the regularity theorem does not apply

**My Proof:**
First we prove that the function $w(x)$ is infinitely differentiable. The function to be infinitely differentiable, one would need to show that in the limit the function $w(x)$, and all its derivatives, go to zero as $x$ goes to $0$.  Since $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ is smooth for $x \neq 0$ and $x \mapsto e^x$ is smooth, it is clear that $w$ is smooth for $x \neq 0$.

Suppose $x \ne 0$, then ${w}^{(k)}$ has the form ${w}^{(k)}(x) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p_k({1 \over x})$ for some polynomial $p_k$. This is clearly true for $k=0$, so suppose it is true for $k=0,...,n$. Then ${w}^{(n)}(x) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p_n({1 \over x})$ and the chain rule gives

$${w}^{(n+1))}(x) = {w}^{(1)}(x) p_n({1 \over x}) - {w}^{(0)}(x) p_n'({1 \over x}) ({1 \over x^2}) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} \left({2 \over x^3}p_n({1 \over x})-p_n'({1 \over x}) ({1 \over x^2}) \right).$$

If $p_{n+1}(y) = 2 y^3p_n(y)-p_n'(y) y^2 $, then ${w}^{(n+1))}(x) = e^{-{1 \over x^2}} 
p_{n+1}( {1 \over x} ) $, and so the result is true for all $n$. If $x \neq 0$, we have $e^{-{1 \over x^2}} = {1 \over {e^{1 \over x^2}}}$, and since $e^{1 \over x^2} \ge \sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!} {1 \over x^{2k}}$, we have

$$e^{-{1 \over x^2}}  \le {x^{2n} \over \sum_{k=0}^n {1 \over k!} {x^{2(n-k)}}} \le {x^{2n} \over n!}$$.

Suppose $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$. Then for any $n$ we see that there is some constant $K$ such that $|e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p({1\over x})| \le K |x|^{2n-d}$ whenever $0 <|x| \le 1$. In particular, there is some $K$ such that
$|e^{-{1 \over x^2}} p({1\over x})| \le K x^2$ for all $0 < |x| \le 1$. We have ${w}^{(0)}(x) \le x^2$ for all $x$, and so ${w}$ is continuous at $x=0$. Since
$|{w}^{(0)}(x) - {w}^{(0)}(0) -0| \le x^2$, we see that ${w}^{(0)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and ${w}^{(1)}(0) = 0$.

Now suppose ${w}^{(k)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$ and ${w}^{(k)}(0) = 0$ for $k=0,...,n$. Then
$|{w}^{(n)}(x) - {w}^{(n)}(0) -0| \le K x^2$ for some $K$ and $|x| \le 1$. Hence
${w}^{(n)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$, and ${w}^{(n+1)}(0) = 0$. With a similar argument we find that the function

$$
\cos {\pi \over x} + i \sin \frac \pi x= \begin{cases}
e^{- \frac{\pi}{x}},& x\not = 0\\
0, & x=0
\end{cases}$$
is infinitely differentiable. Therefore, $\cos{\frac \pi x}$ and $\sin \frac{\pi}{x}$ are smooth functions. Since the summation and product of smooth functions is smooth function then $f$, defined above, is smooth.

Next step is showing $f(x,\xi)$ is convex w.r.t. $\xi$. For notational simplicity we put
$$g=2 x \sin \frac{\pi}{x} + \pi \cos\frac{\pi}{x}.,$$
then for fix $x \in [-1,1]$, we have $f(\xi)= w^2(\xi-g)^2$ is a convex function, for let $\lambda\in [0,1]$, then
\begin{align*}
&f(x,\lambda \xi_1 + (1-\lambda) \xi_2) - \lambda \xi_1 f( \xi_1) -  (1-\lambda) f(\xi_2) =\\
&\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,w^2(\lambda \xi_1 + (1-\lambda) \xi_2 -g)^2 - \lambda  w^2( \xi_1-g)^2 -  (1-\lambda) w^2(\xi_2-g)^2 \\
&=w^2(\lambda (\xi_1-g) + (1-\lambda) (\xi_2 -g))^2 - \lambda  w^2( \xi_1-g)^2 -  (1-\lambda) w^2(\xi_2-g)^2 \\
&=w^2(\lambda^2 (\xi_1-g)^2 +2\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g)  +  (1-\lambda)^2 (\xi_2 -g)^2 -\lambda( \xi_1-g)^2 -(1-\lambda)(\xi_2-g)^2  ) \\
&= w^2( (\lambda^2-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)^2 + 2\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g) + ((1-\lambda)^2 - (1-\lambda) ) (\xi_2 -g)^2)\\
&= w^2(\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)^2 +2\lambda(1-\lambda)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g) + \lambda(1-\lambda) (\xi_2 -g)^2)\\
&= \lambda(1-\lambda)w^2( (\xi_1-g)^2 + 2)(\xi_1-g)(\xi_2 -g) + (\xi_2 -g)^2) \\
&= \lambda(1-\lambda)w^2((\xi_1-g) + (\xi_2 -g))^2 \geq 0 
\end{align*}

(The last inequality is as a product of two non-negative numbers and two square numbers is non-negative)

Could you please help with the other steps!